# How hazelcast-jet achieves anything different from hazelcast EntryProcessors

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

How hazelcast-jet achieves anything vastly different from what was earlier achievable by submitting EntryProcessors on keys in an IMap?

Curious to know.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [InfoQ article](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/02/HazlecastJetOSS) on Jet:

> Sending a runnable to a partition is analogous to the work of a single DAG vertex. The advantage of Jet comes from the ability to have the vertex transform the data it reads, producing items which no longer belong to the same partition, then reshuffle them while sending to the downstream vertex so they are again correctly partitioned. This is essential for any kind of map-reduce operation where the reducing unit must observe all the data items with the same key. To minimize network traffic, Jet can first reduce the data slice produced on the local member, then send only one item per key to the remote member that combines the partial results.

And note that this is just an advantage in the context of the same or similar use cases currently covered by entry processors. Jet can take data from any source and make use of the whole cluster's computational resources to process it.

Comment: Any out of the box way to watch for events, say on an IMap or Queue and trigger computations?

Comment: Registering an event listener on those objects which fires a Jet job seems like a reasonable approach to me.